# How to stream data from database via REST API?

Tags: database, apache-spark, apache-kafka, django-rest-framework, streaming

I have large data stored in Postres database and I need to send the data to the client via a REST API using Django. The requirement is to send the data in chunks and to not load the entire content into memory at once. I understand that there is a StreamingHttpResponse class in Django which I will explore. But are there any other better options? I've heard about Kafka and Spark for streaming applications but the tutorials I've checked about these two tend to involve streaming live data like interacting with Twitter data, etc. But is it possible to stream data from database using any of these two? If yes, how do I then integrate it with REST so that clients can interact with it? Any leads would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You could use [debezium](/questions/tagged/debezium) or [apache-kafka-connect](/questions/tagged/apache-kafka-connect) to bulk load your database into Kafka.

Once the data is there, you can either put a Kafka consumer within your Django application or outside of it and make REST requests as messages are consumed. Spark isn't completely necessary, and shouldn't be used within Django